# Running Time Analysis in big-O

Tags: algorithm, big-o, upperbound

What will the upper bound of following algorithm, which reverses every word of a given sentence:

```
for i = 1 to n
     if(space is found)
         reverse(word)
```

For example, sentence = "Run Time Analysis"

=>output will be "nuR emiT sisylanA"

Will is be O(n^2)? or O(n)? Assuming ***reverse(word)*** runs a loop of word length.

Comment: **Hint:**  It's possible to write the algorithm so that each character is touched only twice... Once to identify each word, once to reverse each word.  Can you see that?

Comment: Yes... It does the same thing. Outer loop will always start from beginning of next word in sentence. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is O(n) because even you have to reverse the past string the number of iterations would be O(2n) but 2n is depreciable so O(n) is the answer, because when n is big the factor of 2 is depreciable.

Comment: What if you have 'm' strings  of 'n/m' characters in the sentence?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your example but lets say "n" is the number of characters in a sentence example string x = "hds ew re2 qed"; the length is 14 the maximum number of iterations that you could make on this algorithm is 14*2 or less that makes that algorithm O(n). or are you reversing all the past strings each time you find a space?

Comment: No,, i am reversing a word once, as shown in the example in question. But I am saying, lets assume we have a **sentence = "<word1> <word2>....<wordm>"**. Now each word is of length _n/m_ and reverse(word) method will run in O(n/m). Does it make the algorithm run in O(n^2) _i.e_ Sigma(n=1 to n/m){O(n/m)}?

Comment: whatch my other answer

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I totally agree with your analysis!

Comment: Thank you, and I will try to work harder when giving an answer :)

Comment: I do not like begging for points but if my answer was correct would appreciate if brands like correct answer: p.

Answer (score 2):

This is mi prove

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int iterations; // Number of iteration that the code will run
string sentence; //The sentece that you want to reverse

void reverse (int start, int end) 
{
    for (int i = start, k = 0; k <= ((end-start)/2); i++, k++) {
        //swap( sentence[i], sentence[end-i] );
        /* This is a swap */
        char keep = sentence[i];
        sentence[i] = sentence[(end-k)];
        sentence[(end-k)] = keep;
        iterations++;
    }

}
 //4 - 7 time 7 - 4 = 3/2 = 1 
int main() {

    sentence = "Run Time Analysis";
    string origin = sentence;
    int len = sentence.length(), start = 0, end = 0;

    iterations = 0; //Starts from 0

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (sentence[i] == ' '  || i == (len-1)) {
            i = (i==len-1) ? (i+1) : i;
            end = i-1;
            reverse(start, end);    
            start = i+1;
        }
        iterations++;
    }
    cout  << "Orginal sentence: " << origin << "\nResult: " << sentence << "\nLength of the sentence: " << len << "\nNumber of iterations: " << iterations << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The result of doing this algorithm is **O(n)** http://ideone.com/1I4QCY
. If this can not convince you then I don't know.

**RESULT**

```
Orginal sentence: Run Time Analysis, 
Result: nuR emiT sisylanA, 
Length of the sentence: 17, 
Number of iterations: 25
```